Search 2D space for optimal location to "bomb".
I am having trouble even searching for references here, do to not knowing the terminology.
Well, and there are so many hits that are not this but just about overlap tests.

Given a 2D (floating point) space with some width, height.
(tends to be in the 50k-100k range)

Given this space has an arbitrary number of "actors" defined by a position and radius.
(literally circles, typically in ~4 clusters, and within a cluster many circles will overlap)
(radii tend to be in the 100-1k range)

Given a circular weapon "area of effect" defined by a radius.
(also, literally a circle, tends to be in the 5k-20k range)


Find the optimal location, or location range, to "drop" the weapon so that it hits the greatest number of actors.
(only overlap is needed, full containment of the actor is not)
(the actual BEST answer is required. so breaking the search down to a fixed grid not sufficient, this is a floating-point number space).
Notes:
This type of problem and the need for a solution, occur frequently in video games and/or video game ai. That is the real-world context of the problem.
However, despite seeing the code for a lot of games and engines, professionally and non-professionally, the only occasion in which ive seen an actual solution to this, is when the game is a regular grid and it exhaustively, expensively, considers every single possible tile. More typically, there is no grid, and we will never know the actual best answer because the algorithm is monte-carlo: try x times then either pick best so far, or expand search area and try x more times.
But .. the thing that rubs me wrong here, is I feel quite certain that there is an algorithmic solution here that will give the ACTUAL best answer, in a reasonably linear amount of search time, and work without a fixed grid. And, I need your help finding it ;D

Let's say you have a solution. Then this solution features a single point that is closest to the border. Draw the shortest line between this border and the point, then move the circle along this line till the point is on the border. This circle still contains all points it did initially.
Next, rotate the circle around the point at the border till there's two points at the border (without any other points leaving the circle).
As result we get that there's an optimal solution that has two of the points on its border. So for all two-pairs of points, compute the possible circles of given radius that has them on the border, and check for each other point whether it's in the circle.
Total time complexity: $\mathcal O(n^3)$

This is starting to sound like the kind of solution i am looking for, but .. it is still essentially starting with a random initial start, and then testing against everything else. If you first imagine the solution on a grid, then how to expand it to not be, i feel that approach has more merit. eg, for each agent, expand its radius by the weapon radius, this represents all locations you could choose which would contain it. Then, find all such area overlaps (somehow efficiently) and find the point or area of maximum number of overlaps.

I think searches in 2D space could perhaps be separated into two separate 1D searches .. then assume rectangular/manhattan distance between them to get a rough cull, then .. i don't know.

@James Brute-force would instead be to test for each subset whether the middle point is close enough to each point so that a bomb placed on that point would hit all. As you have to test for each subset, it has exponential complexity, so $\mathcal O (n^3)$ is a major speed-up

In the scenario that a solution is needed, the number of agents in the scene can be quite high. Anywhere from 100 to 1000. If the test needs to be repeated with each of those as a candidate starting point, it is likely too expensive. But you have framed this in an interesting way, geometrically.

I am imagining that it will be necessary to have a list of all actors sorted by x, and another sorted by y, so that given a min-max value range, one can quickly find what it would contain, by binary searching for the min, then iterating until max is exceeded. This or any other sort of 'search acceleration' work can be delayed to occur less frequently than the searches, and operating on slightly stale agent positions is not a deal breaker, usually.

Sure, there are probably a lot of optimizations that can improve the speed somewhat. E.g. if the radius of the bomb is small, you can fit a grid with its diameter, and instantly get an upper and lower bound on the number of targets hit (1 cell or 4 cells of a square respectively). Then you can sort out all agents who are only part of 4-cell-squares that are below the lower bound. While optimizations like that will often help immensely, they for usual don't improve the Landau-Worst-Case-Time though.

It is noteworthy though that there is typically a large amount of agent overlap here. So there could be 1k agents but effectively there are 4 clusters of 250, and some of those clusters could be nearly completely on top of one another. In such a situation id hope to do something more efficient than checking all against all.
